# In grid view my Row doesnot updated nor deleted

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have a grid view in which I want to apply CRUD operation. When I click on Update button it says:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object at new_OCRS.Admin.gvReportCrime_RowUpdating(Object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e) "

When I click on delete button , it does not show any error but value is not deleted.

Here is my code

```
 protected void gvReportCrime_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
 {
    try
    {

        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            string query = "UPDATE reportcrime SET Name=@Name,Phone1=@Phone1,Phone1,Phone2=Phone2,Email=@Email,Gender=@Gender,City=@City,Address=@Address,CrimeType=@CrimeType,CrimeDetail=@CrimeDetail WHERE CNIC = @CNIC";
            MySqlCommand mscmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
            mscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", (gvReportCrime.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtName") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
            mscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNo.1", (gvReportCrime.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtPhone1") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
            mscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNo.2", (gvReportCrime.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtPhone2") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
            mscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", (gvReportCrime.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEmail") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
            mscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", (gvReportCrime.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtGender") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
            mscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CityName", (gvReportCrime.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtCity") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
            mscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostalAddress", (gvReportCrime.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtAddress") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
            mscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CrimeType", (gvReportCrime.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtCrimeType") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
            mscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CrimeDetail", (gvReportCrime.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtCrimeDetail") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
            mscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CNICNO",Convert.ToString(gvReportCrime.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()));
            mscmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            gvReportCrime.EditIndex = -1;
            BindData();

        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
            Response.Write("" + ex);
    }

 }

 protected void gvReportCrime_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                con.Open();
                string query = "DELETE FROM reportcrime SET WHERE CNIC = @CNIC";
                MySqlCommand mscmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
                mscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CNIC", Convert.ToString(gvReportCrime.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()));
                mscmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                BindData();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("" + ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Code improved, grammar enhanced

Answer (score 0):

Your AddWithValue parameters do not match your Update Query. For example, you have below

```
mscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNo.1",...)
```

But @ContactNo.1 is missing in your Update statement.
Similarly there are others. You need to fix that.

Comment: please post the updated code with the fixes if you have done so that it is helpful to see what you have.

Comment: it is showing null references on this line " mscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", (gvReportCrime.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtName") as TextBox).Text.Trim());"

Comment: You need to put a breakpoint on that line and see what is Null.

Answer (score 0):

```
i have changed my code , @skimad but still same error.
string query = "UPDATE reportcrime SET Name=@Name,Phone1=@Phone1,Phone2=@Phone2,Email=@Email,Gender=@Gender,City=@City,Address=@Address,CrimeType=@CrimeType,CrimeDetail=@CrimeDetail WHERE CNIC = @CNIC";
                    MySqlCommand mscmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
                    mscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", (gvReportCrime.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtName") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                    mscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtPhone1", (gvReportCrime.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtPhone1") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                    mscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtPhone2", (gvReportCrime.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtPhone2") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                    mscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtEmail", (gvReportCrime.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEmail") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                    mscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", (gvReportCrime.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtGender") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                    mscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", (gvReportCrime.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtCity") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                    mscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", (gvReportCrime.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtAddress") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                    mscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CrimeType", (gvReportCrime.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtCrimeType") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                    mscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CrimeDetail", (gvReportCrime.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtCrimeDetail") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                    mscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CNIC",Convert.ToString(gvReportCrime.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()));
                    mscmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

The message "**Object not set to instance of Object**" means that you are trying to use an object which has not been initialized. That is, you either set it to null, or you never set it to anything at all. The **runtime** throwing a **NullReferenceException** always means the same thing: you are trying to use a reference.

Use a breakpoint in your method and check where the value is being null